# What does Null module do in Python asyncio.windows_event package

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am reverse engineering for the purpose of fixing a script in Python. There is nothing about

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
```

on the internet, and the documentation of asyncio is a little ambiguous. What does this line do? If I remove this line, will this affect the functionality of the code in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from asyncio.windows_events import NULL
```

means exactly to import the name `NULL` from the module [`asyncio.windows_events`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/windows_events.py).

[That name is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/windows_events.py#L36) a re-export of `_winapi.NULL`.

[`_winapi`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c9ed0327a9c741a1808926b409df29467baf303a/Modules/_winapi.c) is an extension module that is only compiled on Windows, [and `_winapi.NULL` is exactly the integer `0`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c9ed0327a9c741a1808926b409df29467baf303a/Modules/_winapi.c#L2224).

In other words, you could probably replace that line with

```
NULL = 0
```

Comment: so, it has nothing to do with ActiveX commandbar? it is just for error showing in windows. thanx

Comment: It's... not for "error showing in Windows", it's an import of the `NULL` name for whatever `asyncio` needs it for.

Comment: further deep dive I will do by myself. One question, does it have relation to writing Excel Macros (vba) codes from python script?

Comment: Probably not a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that looks like

```
from some.package import something
```

means that the name `something` (it could be a class, a function, a variable, or etc) is being imported from `some.package`, and you will need to refer to this package's documentation (or in the worst case its source code) to figure out what exactly the declaration does. Though often, the code which does the `import` will make its purpose clear enough, even if you don't know exactly how the name is eventually defined.

Removing the `import` will break your code unless `something` was unused in the first place. Now Python won't know what `something` refers to.